# Blocked from applying for other jobs in company

Tags: job-search, termination, complaint, internal-transfer

I have worked for my current employer for almost 14 years, working from home.  There was an incident a couple of years back where I was unable to work because the company-provided equipment was not working.  I was on the phone or in the office with Tech Support every day for 4 days before the issue was resolved; however, my manager docked my vacation time by 16 of those hours even though I was working (either directly or indirectly while waiting for Tech Support).  I had also tried to go work in the office for two of those days but was told by a lead that there were no desks or computers available. (She later lied to the manager and said she hadn't said that.)

I complained to HR about my hours being taken but nothing was done.  When I attended a meeting with the CEO and he announced that he wanted to know if anyone was having problems, I emailed him to let him know what had happened.  He pushed it off to his HR manager to investigate.  So, when the HR manager called me, I told him what had happened and that the HR person hadn't done anything.

Now, I am being blocked from transferring out of the department.  I have applied for MULTIPLE jobs for which I meet all required qualifications, but am being turned down before I even get an interview.  I am sure I am being blocked by HR.  Is there anything I can do?

As an additional fact, now our department is cutting workforce by 25%.  I am pretty confident that they will put me on this list to get rid of me and I will have nowhere to go because they won't let me apply for other jobs.

Thank you for any help to can provide.

Comment: How much of this do you have in writing or can you prove in any way? Did you keep a record of who helped you from Tech Support? If you want to fight to stay in the company, that is the kind of information you will need. As Joe Strazzere suggests, you should probably start considering other options...

Comment: No where in here do you mention anything about any sort of documentation you presented or kept.  How did your manager inform you that your vacation time was docked?  How does your company log tech support tickets?  How did you tell a lead you'd like to come into the office for a few days and how did they tell you that there was no space?  Was none of this done via email?

Comment: Is transferring out of the dept the only option you're considering? E.g. have you considered trying to level with your superiors about the issues. Maybe if you sat down with them for a few minutes face to face to explain your side of the problem (rather than going behind their back straight to the CEO).

Comment: Note that in some companies, underperformers may not be transferred (even if the reason they were down-rated boils down to interpersonal issues with their manager) . If you're in that position you can either improve your rating and then ask for a transfer, or try to challenge the performance rating (difficult unless you have a very good argument _and_ another group that actively wants you), or start preparing to move elsewhere.

Comment: You might not be able to take other jobs in the company, but have you considered looking for jobs with other companies? It might be a good idea, given the way you're being treated.

Comment: *"I am sure I am being blocked by HR"* I see no evidence of that in your question. Unless you have direct evidence I suggest you [edit] your question and change the wording to "*I feel*" or "*I suspect*"

Answer (score 4):

> Now, I am being blocked from transferring out of the department... I am sure I am being blocked by HR. Is there anything I can do?

No - there is nothing you can do to change this.  If HR is not allowing you to interview, nothing anyone else can do (besides the CEO, whom you've talked to) will change this.  This does not bode well for you.  Generally this means that your boss has intentionally blocked you, usually by putting you on some kind of "Improvement Plan."

> As an additional fact, now our department is cutting workforce by 25%. I am pretty confident that they will put me on this list to get rid of me

If you believe you are about to get axed, then you should be looking for another job now.  The best reference for a new job is already having one.  Do not wait to be let go before you start looking.  From your post - it sounds like your tenure with your current company may come to an end very soon.

**If you want to try and keep your job**, stop talking to HR and the CEO, and talk to your manager.  Its preferable to do this in person.  During this meeting, tell your manager you feel he is not happy with your work, and ask how you can improve.  If he tells you how to improve, do that.  Realize the decision to let you go may have already been made.

**No matter what, start looking for another job during non-work hours.**

Answer (score 4):

First I want to mention that your story has a lot of holes in it.  You have had these pretty minor issues over 14 years and your recourse was to email the CEO?

What you should have done was follow up with your manager on all of these things.  And anything that is big enough to talk about after the fact should be followed up with an email or some sort of documentation.  HR should have gotten involved with this with you manager passing it to them or if your manager not following up then you would go to HR.  HR should not have gotten a note from the CEO.  It makes you seem like a malcontent, a whiner, and someone who doesn't understand the organization and someone who doesn't follow up properly.

Given most of what you are saying is true I would say this:

1. You may be blackballed by the CEO/HR.  If you are there isn't anything you are going to do about it other than get another job.
2. Maybe you aren't blackballed but the jobs you wanted were targeted at an employee.  A lot of times at my company the hiring manager has an idea who they want or what group they want a person from given they are getting someone from within.
3. So either way a good way to get past your issues is to start applying for jobs within your organization and email the hiring manager for those jobs.  About 10 years ago I felt like I was blackballed at my company (and I have heard from HR later that I was) because I gave my manager a bad review.  I was in a very similar situation, applied for 4-5 jobs that I was overqualified for just to leave his group.  The first time I sent an email to a hiring manager (different location) I heard back from him and was hired within a few weeks.  The hiring manager even told me that my old boss did not recommend me - but he found 5 other employees that gave me a great recommendation.  So two tidbits here, email hiring manager and find other employees that will vouch for your good work.
4. I work from home a lot too.  You don't have to show up at the office to get a raise or a better job.  In fact if I showed up to my office (500+ employees) nobody from my group would know because they are in other centers.  My advice is to communicate with your group more and make sure you are part of projects and development for your team.  If you just do your job and that's it why should you get promoted?  Working from home you have to show added value and talk to your team.  Promotions come from mainly 3 places, tenure at a job (and this seems to be getting you no where and this is usually a slow process anyway), showing superior skills/knowledge/abilities to your current job, and forming relationships with the decision makers.
5. Start applying for outside jobs.  If you think they will get rid of you, they probably will.  I would try to have something lined up before the layoffs to see if it is worth going through these.  Also it is usually easier to find a job if you have one.